# orientation landscape but 180 degrees forward

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I have in my `buildozer.spec` set orientation landscape. It is good, but
I need it to turn it around 180 degrees, because it the current state I have volume control
physical phone buttons at the bottom and I would like to have them at the top of the screen.

Can I switch it to easily 180 degrees without changing layout completely?

Comment: It's easy to set that orientation, but I'm not sure if buildozer has an option for it. You could do it with pyjnius easily enough, the method [here](https://github.com/inclement/pyjnius-api-wrappers/blob/master/orientation.py) probably still works.

Comment: @inclement I already set the orientation to `sensorLandscape` in `buildozer.spec` and it helped. So, delete this question, or let it for others?

Comment: If you have found a satisfactory answer, write it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the orientation to `sensorLandscape` in `buildozer.spec` and it helped.